# React Redux mapDispatchToProps error

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to apply mapDispatchToProps instead of Dispatch action ,
but i got a error msg ,anyone help? Thabkyou

***mapDispatchToProps() in Connect(ButtonGroup) must return a plain object. Instead received undefined.***

---

**Action creator**

```
function clickDisable() {
  return {
      type: 'CLICK_DISABLE'
  }
}
```

**Component**

```
var ButtonGroup = React.createClass({


     clickAdd(event) {  
            this.props.dispatch(clickAdd());  
        }  ,

    clickSub(event) {  
            this.props.dispatch(clickSub());  
        }  ,
    /*clickDisable(event) {  
            this.props.dispatch(clickDisable());  
        }  ,*/

  render() {

      const { age } = this.props;     

        return (
          <ButtonToolbar style={{width: 17+ 'em'}} >
          <Button  id="search"   style={{width: 5 + 'em'}}>{age}</Button>
          <Button  onClick={this.clickAdd} style={{width: 5 + 'em'}}>Createa</Button>
          <Button  onClick={this.props.clickDisable} style={{width: 5 + 'em'}}>Detele</Button>
          </ButtonToolbar> 
        );
      }
});
```

**mapDispatchToProps**

```
 function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch) {
        return Redux.bindActionCreators({
            clickDisable: clickDisable
      }, dispatch);
     }

    function mapStateToProps(state) {  
        return {  
            age: state.reducreForAge.age
        }  
    }
```

**Connect**

```
  const NewButtonGroup = connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(ButtonGroup);
```

Comment: Which line causes the error? Everything in the code you show here looks fine.

Comment: looks good on a glance could you make a working codesandbox  out of your code ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this in mapDispatchToProps. Everything else looks fine.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>  { return{
clickDisable: () => dispatch({type:'CLICK_DISABLE'})};};
```

Comment: Your answer should give the exact behavior as the OP's code.